# System.Web.Mvc Vs Microsoft.Web.Mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, class, namespaces

I just started ASP.NET MVC, and the first thing that got me confused is on MSDN there is a [System.Web.Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) namespace, and then there is a [Microsoft.Web.Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.web.mvc%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) namespace. I'd like to know -

1. Why are there two different root namespaces for ASP.NET MVC framework library classes?
2. Based on what the classes go under one root namespace or the other?

Thanks in Advance.

**NOTE:** I did google search, and found nothing about it.

Comment: Why are the down votes and closing votes? I don't understand what is wrong in asking this question? Down voters, could you at least add a comment explaining your action?

Comment: `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` is the MVC Futures project. [Refer Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-beta-released#ten)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks for being helpful, and the link :) Could you please post this as an answer, so that I can accept?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` namespace if for the MVC Futures project, which is for features that the MVC team may or may not include in future versions of ASP.NET MVC. There is very little documentation associated with it, but you can view the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

As an example, it includes the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Controls` namespace, which is discussed in [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/asp-net-mvc-release-candidate-2-i-declare-myself-to-be-declarative), but it never got off the ground.