# NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support 'newer version' as a target

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've created a simple ASP.NET CORE 6 Web API. I then pushed it to Github. When I try to create a pipeline in **Azure Devops**, I'm getting the error.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET
   .TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support 
   targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports 
   .NET 6.0.
```

I've just downloaded VS 2022 community edition. I've installed .Net SDK 6.
Here's my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I chose what Azure devops suggested, so this is my yml file

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

 trigger:
  - master

 pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

 variables:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'

 steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
        /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
        /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

   - task: VSTest@2
       inputs:
         platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
         configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I've followed what's said in t[his documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1045), but it's not working. The build is still failing like this

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading this 2 links, it there were 2 issues with the template from Azure devops.

1. the restore packages kept on looking for SDK 5. So this task fixed the issue. I've to include a step that mentions SDK 6. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops
2. also it kept on targeting Visual Studio 2019, which doesn't support .NET 6.0.x. Therefore, instead of `vmImage: 'windows-latest'`, using `vmImage: 'windows-2022'` allow the build to succeed https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6907.

I ended up using the classic template so that I can understand better how the pipeline works. 1) Either using ubuntu-latest or windows-2022. 2) add a step for the version of SDK.

[image]

Comment: You are spot on. Using **vmImage: 'windows-2022'** instead of **vmImage: 'windows-latest'** forces the pipelines to use .NET 6

Answer (score -1):

> I chose what Azure devops suggested, so this is my yml file

Unfortunately it's easy to confuse things, since Microsoft's naming is [anything but consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391202/4424236).
You need to use .NET Core guide for this: [Build, test, and deploy .NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core)

To save you time, here is a simple YAML pipeline to build ASP.NET Core applications:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

# Setup pipeline-level variables to keep things DRY
variables:
  configuration: Release
  projects: '**/*.csproj'
  publish_dir: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  vm_image: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: dotnet
        displayName: .NET

        pool:
          vmImage: $(vm_image)

        # Run builds in latest .NET 6 SDK container (Debian 11)
        # This simplifies things and allows to easily target different SDKs:
        # https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk
        container: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim

        workspace:
          clean: all

        # Build tasks a separated (restore/build/test/publish)
        # to make it easier to catch/debug issues
        steps:
          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: .NET | Restore [$(configuration)]
            inputs:
              command: restore
              projects: $(projects)

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: .NET | Build [$(configuration)]
            inputs:
              command: build
              projects: $(projects)
              arguments: --configuration $(configuration) --no-restore

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: .NET | Test [$(configuration)]
            inputs:
              command: test
              projects: $(projects)
              publishTestResults: true
              arguments: --configuration $(configuration) --no-restore --no-build

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: .NET | Publish [$(configuration)]
            inputs:
              command: publish
              publishWebProjects: true
              zipAfterPublish: true
              modifyOutputPath: true
              arguments: --configuration $(configuration) --output $(publish_dir) --no-restore --no-build

          # Publish zipped build results so they can be downloaded from the pipeline UI
          - publish: $(publish_dir)
            displayName: Artifact | Publish
            artifact: $(Build.DefinitionName)
```