# How can I redirect and display a database image in a new tab using ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to display my database image into new tab when user click on the image.

I can do it with with static images because that time I have their static image url.

But I do not have any idea about how to do it with dynamic images.

Please help. A warm thanks in advance

This is my C# code - `File1.aspx`:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="independence">
             <figure class="column">
                 <asp:ImageButton CssClass="inimg" ID="Image1" OnClick="Image1_Click" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Picture","Admin/AdminGallery/Events/{0}") %>' />
             </figure>
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

`File1.cs`:

```
protected void Image1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect();
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you are using WebForms in 2023?

Comment: Because I am developing a web app in ASP.NET framework, in visual studio IDE

Comment: WebForms has been effectively obsolete [since 2008 when it was replaced by ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391202/159145) (and replaced _again_ by ASP.NET Core in 2016) - if this is a new project for you then you should be using _only_ ASP.NET Core. Don't use WebForms for new projects today.

Comment: One more reason, DOTNET V7 is on demanding nowadays so I decided to try it. Genuinely I am a python dev.

Comment: .NET 7 doesn't support WebForms at all - .NET Framework 4.x (released in 2010-2015) is the last version to support WebForms.

Comment: Thank you, I will lay my hands on Core too. But it is just for my practice, somebody suggested me to practice with ASP.NET Framework then go for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I understand what you are saying dear sir. And I will switch to core ASAP but please help me with this question i poseted.

Comment: You received bad advice. I recommend people _avoid_ WebForms entirely because it encourages bad programming habits (`Page` is stateful, PostBacks break the browser's Back button, you can't do automated testing, no support for abstrating away `HttpContext`, no support for C# `#nullable` types, the `WebControls` all generate atrocious HTML that's designed for IE6... and so on and so on). so: _just don't_.

Comment: Webforms or not, you cannot open a new tab from the backend.

Comment: even with javascript?

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript. And you can easy do this with web forms. Nothing wrong with learning and using web forms. In fact, some of the best new features in vs2022 are for web forms as outlined here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/

Comment: You can try modifying your ImageButton to call this JavaScript function: You can try modifying your ImageButton to call this JavaScript function: <asp:ImageButton CssClass="inimg" ID="Image1" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# "openImageInNewTab(\'' + Eval("Picture" ,"Admin/AdminGallery/Events/{0}") + '\'); return false;" %>'
     ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Picture","Admin/AdminGallery/Events/{0}") %>' />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

First, the markup for the ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td><asp:Label ID="FighterLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fighter") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="EngineLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Engine") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ThrustLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Thrust") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
            <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageView" runat="server" Width="200px"
                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>'
                OnClick='<%# $@"window.open(""ViewFighter.aspx?ID={Eval("ID")}"")" %>'
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="table table-hover">
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server">Fighter</th>
                <th runat="server">Engine</th>
                <th runat="server">Thrust</th>
                <th runat="server">Description</th>
                <th runat="server">View</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And code behind to load up the ListView data:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM Fighters ORDER BY Fighter");
        ListView1.DataBind();   
    }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

And the target page ViewFighter.aspx has this markup:

```
        <h3 id="myheading" runat="server"></h3>

        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="80%" />
```

And code behind assumes a URL with ID having been passed.

```
e.g., this: ViewFighter.aspx?ID=3
```

So, code behind for this target page is:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
            {
                int PK = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters WHERE ID = @ID");
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK;
                DataRow rFigher = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL).Rows[0];
                myheading.InnerText = rFigher["Fighter"].ToString();
                Image1.ImageUrl = rFigher["ImagePath"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, you don't have to actually write a JavaScript function, but the image button does require what amounts to code as an JavaScript expression. That JavaScript code opens a new tab, and redirects the page to open ViewFighter.aspx in a new tab.

Above assumes an image path is stored in the database. However, the above approach would also work fine if the actual image was stored in the database column as opposed to an image path.

If you are storing a raw binary image in the database column, then I can add a few lines of code to above that demonstrates how the image could come from the database, and not using a path. (just ask in the comments, and I post additional code).

In above, I used 2 global helper routines that returns a data table from given SQL text, or SQL passed with a SqlCommand object.

Those 2 routines are:

```
    public static DataTable MyRst(string strSQL, string sConn = "")
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        if (sConn == "")
            sConn = Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }


public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL, string sCon = "")
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    if (sCon == "")
        sCon = Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this then.

```
protected void Page_Load() {
    this.Form.Target = "_blank"; 
}
```

Comment: This won't work: `Image1` exists within an `ItemTemplate` so it won't be exposed as a property of the parent Page. You'll need to use WebForm's DataBinding events along with `FindControl`.

Comment: you mean like this.
Image imgpath=(Image).FindControl("Image1");

Comment: you don't need find control at all. See my posted working example......